# file_get_contents() fails with multiple concurrent requests

Tags: php

I'm running multiple PHP processes from the command line (using php.exe). Right now I think there are 16 processes (they all run the same thing, just for different clients, I won't go into too many details here for brevity's sake).

All the processes make a `file_get_contents()` call that access the same file, which is a local file, not a URL.
The problem is that, in some cases (and this is pretty erratic), the process fails and there's an error that the file does not exist. But the file clearly does exist and there's nothing even going on that would try to write to it, so I'm assuming that it's failing because `file_get_contents()` is being called to open it too many times simultaneously.

I've managed to get around it with some convoluted code that tries `file_get_contents()` multiple time until it succeeds, but it feels like a hack. I was under the impression that for a read operation there wouldn't be any problem to have many simultaneous processes reading a file, am I missing something here?

Comment: You should look into [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

Comment: Is it static file or updated periodically?

Comment: @Nick J, is flock needed even if all you're doing are reads? I thought it would be mostly useful if you have writes happening at some point. In my case, the error happens even if all I'm doing is calling file_get_contents(), there's no write happening at all.

Comment: @Cheery It's not a static file, technically it could be updated, but in the scenarios that I'm running into errors, it's static, it doesn't change at all, it's all reads.

Comment: @Rocket04 could you try to make a copy of the file and by random read from one of them? Just to check if that problem is related to the php limits or to something else.

Comment: What is the exact string you're sending to get_file_contents, and is it the only parameter? (You can replace all alphanumeric chars with X's for privacy; e.g. `\\XXX\\XXXXX\\XXXX.XXX`)

Comment: @Iserni It's a full path, c:\\wwwroot\\myapp\\config\\def.txt, and yes, it's the only parameter.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#112831